# When does Ax +b = 0 not have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

And does that tell us anything about the properties of matrix A?

Comment: I think you can find something helpfull here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Answer (score 2):

AS far as I know, when $rank(A)\neq rank(A,b)$, there will be no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that tell us, that $A^{-1}$ doesn't exists, because if $A^{-1}$ exists you have:

$$Ax=-b$$

$$x=A^{-1}(-b)$$

Comment: This may be a long shot, but does that infer anything about whether A is positive definite or positive semidefinite?